# What is the benefit of having VM publish and listener in the same application in mule 4?

Tags: mule, mule4

I have seen some applications where I could see vm publish connector and vm listener connector both being used. Will vm listener consumes the payload and do the processing whenever any message comes to publisher?
What is the difference b/w vm listener and vm consume connector. any suggestions on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is used when you want to decouple the processing of a message from the flow that originates it. The VM connector is like an in memory queue. The publish operation allows to put a message in the queue. After that the flow can continue to operate. The listener message source reads a message from the queue and starts another flow, asynchronously. That means it is send-and-forget.

The difference between listener and consume is that listener is a message source, it starts a flow when a message arrives. Consume is an operation to read a message of the queue, if available, that it is performed in the middle of a flow.

Comment: Question here I have is, when we are adding vm listener in our flow with particular queue name, does that means the message is being consumed already?  if anything in the listener flow goes wrong, will that message be still there if I have added the queue as persistent?

Comment: That is another question. Please amend your question or post a new question.

Comment: Done. Created a new one.